# Get the minimal amount of code used in JQuery/JSApi (legally)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsapi

I have built a really simple script using JQuery/JSApi. I want to deploy it to my raspberry pi. As such, I need to make it only use the minimal amount of code possible (Pi is already full!).

It will not have a network connection, so let's say I just want to grab one file from the JSApi (as an example - I will not actually do this as it isn't legal).

So, I opened fiddler, opened my webpage, and saw what dependencies it had. After loading the JSApi, it fetched the following two files :

```
GET www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/69d4d6122bf8841d4832e052c2e3bf39/format+en,default+en.I.js HTTP/1.1

GET www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1 HTTP/1.1
```

So, two questions - firstly, is there any legal way for me to get this file and host it locally for JSApi?

Assuming no is the answer to this, let's assume the files are JQuery modules - where I believe this would be allowed. How would I grab them, and point to them locally? When I try to navigate to either of the addresses above, for example, I get an error message or nothing loads - so it is not possible to include these modules (or other JQuery modules) separately ?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to run a tool like gulp or webpack that can bundle and minify your scripts. That will work through the code and remove sections that are clearly unused.

Comment: @ssube The problem here I think is that gulp needs to be installed locally - and my pi is too small to do this. Maybe there is a way around this I am not considering though. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: You'll need to run gulp ahead of time and push the packaged script to your pi (or set up a web service to do that for you and have the pi consume that).

Comment: @ssube Oh I could just deploy the site on my machine locally also ha :). Seems kind of needlessly complicated when it only seems to be fetching one script though, no ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work in your exact setup, but you can do something like the following to get it pared down to the bare essentials:

- Write up your webpage with the full jQuery package and any modules necessary (per your second example)
- Pass all the javascript you're using through something like Google's Closure Compiler: https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home
- Include that compiled javascript, which will include only the absolutely necessary functions.